# Ruby on Rails autocomplete with soulmate URL

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, autocomplete

I'm creating an autocomplete form on my project using Soulmate https://github.com/seatgeek/soulmate using this tutorial as a guideline. http://patshaughnessy.net/2011/11/23/finding-your-soulmate-autocomplete-with-redis-in-rails-3-1

My question is, how do I include the url of the item. e.g. I'm indexing artist and I would like the json object to include the data, url to /artist/1

I need this so my jQuery autocomplete could link to the search results.

Thanks,

Comment: can you link to the particular jquery autocompleter you're using? the documentation will have something about how to format your results.

Comment: Hi Kristian, https://github.com/mcrowe/soulmate.js/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going to the link you provided, I see in the docs that they have a rendering callback function, presumably meant to make use of your ajax responses.

Notice how I simply returned what I wanted the list item to contain. This may not be completely accurate, but you get the idea. look in the docs further for more information. (there doesn't seem to be a lot of documentation written, though.)

```
var render = function(term, data, type){
    var link = "<a href="data.url.or.something">"+term+"</a>";
    return link;
}

$('#search-input').soulmate({
  renderCallback: render, //this is a reference to the function above.
  url:            'http://soulmate.YOUR-DOMAIN.com/search',
  types:          ['type1', 'type2', 'type3', 'type4'],
  selectCallback: select,
  minQueryLength: 2,
  maxResults:     5
});
```

Comment: Hi Kristian, thank you for your help. I also don't know how to include the url of my object in the model. If you look at http://patshaughnessy.net/2011/11/23/finding-your-soulmate-autocomplete-with-redis-in-rails-3-1 - loader.add("term" => name, "id" => id) - My question is, how do I add the url into the redis db?

Comment: this example assumes you will use some sort of canonical url scheme, thus you can put it together in manually in your render function `by/knowing/how/the/struture/will/be`. however, since that's not the case here, since its using ActiveRecord AND Redis, that means one set of the data has a schema and one doesn't. i.e. you must add a url column to your ActiveRecord, and then just remember to add that field to your `loader.add()` method. Then you can `Cherrypick.specific.data` when it returns to the render function. hope that helps. anything further than this would be speculation on my part.

Comment: Hi Kristian, fortunately, I use the FriendlyId gem for the permanent link URL. So there is the slug field in the database. So I can just customize the json render to include the url via the slug field. Thanks for your help!

Comment: sweet! thats good. OK so, upvote and select an answer if you found this helpful.

Comment: Hey Kristian, my reputation is not enough to upvote your answer. Sorry, I wish I can help more

Comment: Hi guys, I have the same problem. I done the server side code. But I want to know in which format I need to pass the objects from server to the client. Suppose I have 4 types `['type1', 'type2', 'type3', 'type4']` 

From the server I am rendering a json object like:

`{"term": "sh", "results": {"type1": [], "type2": [{"term": "Gulf Shores Beach", "score": 15.934646, "data": {"url": "/venues/gulf-shores-beach/tickets/", "subtitle": "Gulf Shores, AL"}, "id": 5135}, {"term": "Shoreline Amphitheatre", "score": 15.435043, "data": {"url": "/venues/shoreline.....`

But its not working. Any idea??